# self.close() or Window.close() not working on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

`Self.close()` is working For IE but For Chrome and Firefox it shows that

**Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.**

And This Page will not a popup and it is not open by java script so what are the alternative way to close window by Script which is not open by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can not close the window by script due to security reasons on chrome and firefox. But there is a workaround posted here.
That works on chrome 40 and latest version as I have tested.

[chrome closing of opened window](https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/javascript-window-close-method-that-still-works/)

Comment: not work on my chrome, my chrome version is 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit).

Answer (score -1):

I know it's too late to answer but none of these solution worked for me . I wrote

```
      onclick="top.window.close();"
```

and it worked .

Comment: Please verify your code before adding.